# How to hide an element in if statement?

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

I am making an html change to a CMS that will affect all pages when the changes are live. I would like this html alert to only affect 1 specific page. I am attempting to do an if statement for the page title.

The logic is that if the page title is `Test Article Two` then show the html that I have put in place, if not then `display=none`. With this logic in place, I am viewing the html on all pages not just the one I want it to show.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="title-wrapper">
            <a href="~/@countryText.ToLower()" title="@countryFullText" alt="@countryText"><span id="article-banner-country">@countryFullText</span></a> /
            <a href="@parentUrl" title="@subCatText" alt="@subCatText"><span id="article-banner-category">@subCatText</span></a>
            <div id="article-banner-title">@pageTitle</div>
        <!--page alert -->

          <div class="feedback-container content-desktop" id="alert-dialog">
    <div class="feedback-left">
      <p>Have any feedback? Reach out to us!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="feedback-right">
        <button class="feedback-button">Give Feedback</button>
        <button class="feedback-button">Dismiss</button>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

function showAlert() { 
     if(@pageTitle === "Test Article Two") {
    document.getElementById('alert-dialog').style.display = 'block'; 
}else {
    document.getElementById('alert-dialog').style.display = 'none'; 
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: I have no idea how your CMS works, but it could be as simple as wrapping your variable in quotes, like `if ("@pageTitle" === "Test Article Two") {`. We could probably help more if you looked at the console and checked for any errors your code is generating.

Comment: I don't have any errors in the console but I did view the sources tab and it appears that the pageTitle is updating as I expect it. For example, @pageTitle is being populated by the correct page title that I am on. So maybe the actual logic involved is what is not correct?

Comment: Well, I'm not seeing where `showAlert()` is being called in your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend changing a class on the `body` element so that you can use `CSS` for the styling.

1. HTML: nothing really changed here

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title-wrapper">
            <a href="~/@countryText.ToLower()" title="@countryFullText" alt="@countryText"><span id="article-banner-country">@countryFullText</span></a> /
            <a href="@parentUrl" title="@subCatText" alt="@subCatText"><span id="article-banner-category">@subCatText</span></a>
            <div id="article-banner-title">@pageTitle</div>
                <div class="feedback-container content-desktop" id="alert-dialog">
                    <div class="feedback-left">
                        <p>Have any feedback? Reach out to us!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="feedback-right">
                        <button class="feedback-button">Give Feedback</button>
                        <button class="feedback-button">Dismiss</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

2. javascript: just check the `document.title` and add the class the the `body` element

```
<script>
    if(document.title === "Test Article Two") {
        document.body.classList.add("show-alert");
    }
</script>
```

3. Use `CSS` for the styling. Always hide `#alert-dialog` and only show it when we add the class to the body.

```
<style>
    #alert-dialog {
        display: none;
    }
    .show-alert #alert-dialog {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are making static pages or using server side rendering, you could add logic to add a class to show or hide the alert element without adding more javascript to the page. It will have the relevant class(es) when the html is generated and delivered. This way you won't have to create a function, call it and manipulate the DOM after everything is rendered.

I may have missed this in the code above, are you calling the showAlert function anywhere? If not, your alert won't be shown (or will be shown depending on the default styles).

One thing I'd caution against is the imperative nature of the code here. If you wanted to reuse this alert functionality on another page, you'd have to add another more logic to detect another page title every time you wanted to use the alert. Since you are using a CMS, you might consider adding a flag to show the alert, and on this specific page, turn that flag on.

If you wanted to use the function strategy, I'd set your default alert styles:

```
#alert-dialog {
display: none;
}
.show {
 display: block;
}
```

and try something like this:

```
<script>
  function showAlert() {
    if(document.title === "Test Article Two") {
        document.getElementById('alert-dialog').classList.add('show');
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", showAlert);
</script>
```

Another alternative is to take a look at the path of the page this is supposed to be on (`window.location.pathname`) and using regex to see if it matches what you want. I'd recommend that over looking at the title since it's more likely the title of the page will change rather than the url.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can access the page title with `document.title`. You should change the script like this:

```js
function showAlert() { 
    if(document.title === "Test Article Two") {
        document.getElementById('alert-dialog').style.display = 'block'; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById('alert-dialog').style.display = 'none'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: the if(@pageTitle) would change to if(document.title) ?

Comment: thank you! I am still seeing the alert on the pages I want to hide it on. is if(document.title === "Test Article Two") the proper way if the title is being populated by @pageTitle?

Comment: @neoslo This would work if `showAlert();` is called somewhere.